# Show that a finite cyclic group of order $n$ has exactly one subgroup of order $d$ dividing $n$ and these are all the subgroups it has

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My attempt

Note- Addition is under $mod$ $d$

Let $G = (a^0,a^1,a^2.....a^{n-1})$

$n=kd$

Let $H_d = (a^{0k},a^{1k},a^{2k}......a^{{(d-1)}k})$

For $a^{z_1k},a^{z_2k} \in H_d$

$a^{z_1k}a^{z_2k} = a^{{(z_1+z_2)}k} \in H_d$

$H_d$ is closed

For $a^{zk} \in H_d$

$a^{zk} (a^{zk})^{-1}=a^0$

$(a^{zk})^{-1} = (a^{-1})^{zk}$

Since $a^{-1}$ is $a^{n-1}$ we can rewrite it as

$(a^{zk})^{-1} = (a^{n-1})^{zk}=a^{z(n-1)k} \in H_d$

Since $(a^{zk})^{-1} \in H_d$ and $H_d$ is closed, $H_d$ is a subgroup.

I can easily prove the 3rd part by using Lagrange's theorem.

I have no idea how to prove that only $1$ subgroup of order $d$ exists. Maybe by proving that the elements of the $2$ groups have to be the same?

I would really appreciate if someone could verify my proof so far and give some hints to complete the proof.

Comment: $\{a^0,a^1,\ldots,a^{n-1}\}$ is more conventional notation for a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show a subgroup $H$ of order $d$ is unique, observe that $b^d$
must be the identity for each $b\in H$. Write $b=a^k$, with $0\le k<n$.
Then $b^d=a^{kd}$, and for this to equal the identity, $kd$ must be a multiple
of $n$, that is $kd/n$ is an integer. This $k$ is a multiple of $n/d$, so that
$b$ is an element of the set $\{a^0,a^{n/d},a^{2n/d},\ldots,a^{n-n/d}\}$. But this
set has exactly $d$ elements so $H$ must equal $\{a^0,a^{n/d},a^{2n/d},\ldots,a^{n-n/d}\}$.

Comment: Hello, you write " This k is a multiple of n/d, ", but just before, you write $k\cdot d/n$, so k is a multiple of $d/n$, not $n/d$? Or I misunderstand.